# Removing reputation limit during private beta

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

It is important for a private beta to obtain a good set quality questions and answers.

> The private beta gives you the opportunity to get the site off to a
>   great start with expert questions and answers. When we open to the
>   public, new users will look at your questions to get an idea of what
>   they should ask.

In order to promote this, wouldn't it be worthwhile temporarily removing the reputation limit?

Comment: How would that help promote participation in the private beta?

Comment: @AnnaLear: By giving more incentive to continue answering questions. But I completely agree with The Unhandled Exception's answer. It's _quality_ that matters, not _quantity_.

Comment: Kind of gives an advantage to older users.  Perhaps a general no-rep-cap until you hit some level of reputation?  Join, no rep cap until you hit 5k?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't agree with this, and have an example.

When I was a member of [the How Things Work](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15025/how-things-work) Stack Exchange site, [one particular user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156564/jacob) *really* wanted to reach 1K to be able to get the mod tools and become a pro-tem mod. Impressively, *even with the rep cap* he was able to reach 1K in (if I recall correctly) 5 days, the minimum possible earning 200 rep every day.

During the first few days of the site, as you said,

> It is important [...] to obtain a good set quality questions and answers.

We're looking for *quality*, not *quantity*. Users should focus on good quality content, not *lots* of content.

Also, [as I know from chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3055525#3055525), the site you're referring to is a bit of an edge case. [It has a lot more questions suddenly appearing](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/isnt-one-user-overseeding-during-the-private-beta) than most betas do 2 days into them, and it has [one extremely dedicated user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166936/ben-brocka) who's trying to "catch them all"

Just my $0.02, downvote if you disagree or don't approve of my using the phrase "gotta catch 'em all"

Comment: That makes perfect sense. ;p Hadn't thought it through. Thanks for the example.

Comment: "earning 200K rep every day" -- that *is* impressive

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I dun made a typo durhhhhhh. What's sad is I didn't see my mistake even after you pointed it out, I had to have someone else call my attention to it! *Glares at Tim Stone*

Answer (score 2):

[Robert](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/56/68) worded it well on Movies.SE

> If anything, the reputation cap is needed more during the private beta. There are far fewer post and everyone is concentrating (and voting) on what little there is to vote on. So, certainly there is an "undue" (or at least a disproportionate) amount of rep being doled out during the private beta.

You should be focusing on getting the rest of the community involved. Starting period is for getting the beta out of the gate. The reputation will come.

And it's only 7 days, kind of a weird feature (that will only be used by a very small group, only 2-3 users ever reach that bracket in beta)  to have for only 7 days.